# OEM Camera Sensors for a computer project

Tags: sensor, diy, electronics

First off I'm not sure if this is the place for this question, but it seems to be the closest fit.

I want to buy a small camera sensor (like for netbooks/phones), from what I have read on wikipedia my target sensor is:

12MP(not that important) 
1080p recording 
CMOS, preferably backlit 
Only have to buy one

now for obvious reasons I want to buy an OEM sensor instead of ripping one out of a camera, also if I where to hook one up to Windows CE, Android, Meego or Linux would I need to make a driver, and where could I buy a sensor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hooking up a raw sensor is a monumental task (for a CMOS sensor, you typically have at roughly one line for each row/column, meaning ~3k x 4K connections stuffed into less than an inch on each side).

A typical netbook, cell phone, etc., uses a packaged camera module with some sort of serial connection to the outside world. You can get some primarily video (i.e., 1.3 - 2 MP range) modules from [Sparkfun Electronics](http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/102) (low resolution, but cheap -- for only one, the shipping may be close to as much as the module itself). For higher resolution, you might consider [Leopard Imaging](https://www.leopardimaging.com/). They have everything from relatively bare modules to complete development boards (with matching version of Linux available for free download).